# Database issues with regards to deploying MVC application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, setup-deployment

Platform: Windows 7 with VS2013, Microsoft Server 2008 R2 and Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Good Day to All.
My partner and I recently created an MVC application which works in localhost with a local database hosted in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 within the computer.

But now what we would like to do is to host this application on a website for our users to use the application.

Hosting has been done, where we managed to get the front page to show, but the issue lies with database connection to the MS SQL Server 2012 within the server.

When we check our SQL error log we see this:

2015-05-26 12:04:38.26 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State:
 38. 
2015-05-26 12:04:38.26 Logon       Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly
 specified database 'HRMS.Models.EmployeeDBContext'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
May I seek some advice as to how we can set up the MVC application on the server to talk to the MS SQL 2012 installed within the server?

We're both new to MVC and ASP.Net, Please guide us in the simplest way possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It means the windows authentication is not working, the hosting might have provided a Database connection string, change the same in web config.

Comment: You can check application pool user identity to get it done(check permission) or else you can use sql authentication to get it work.

Comment: @Dreamweaver - Thanks for your response. We have already attempted to change the connection string to fit the new environment, but it doesn't seem to do anything. As far as we understand:
<add name="_PutAnythingHere_" connectionString="Data Source=_Server'sComputerName_\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=_DBName_;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
We applied the above to web.config, but the application still fails to work.

Comment: @KaushikThanki Thanks for your response. Do you have a guide somewhere we could follow?

Comment: Yes check the Wiktor Zychla answer this is what i was saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection string most probably indicates an **integrated authentication** (`integrated security=true`) which means that the identity of the worker process is trying to connect to the database.

The problem is that you haven't set the identity in an explicit way or rather you set it to the `Network Service` built-in account.

And this account is not listed as permitted to access the database.

You have two options:

1. add permissions to the Network Service to access the database (not recommended)
2. create a separate identity (user) in the server's operating system (or a domain account if you have a catalog) and both assign the identity to the application pool in IIS (so that the ASP.NET process is run under this account) and give this user permissions to access the database.

More on that here:

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thanks for your reply, but now a similar error code popped up  2015-05-26 14:58:11.94 spid53      Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLEXPRESSTempDB'.  2015-05-26 15:00:10.42 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2015-05-26 15:00:10.42 Logon       Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL/_website_stated_in_IIS_manager_'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'HRMS.Models.EmployeeDBContext'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Comment: You now have set up the pool but you **haven't** set up the identity for the pool. Because of this, the pool uses the default identity (`IIS APPPOOL\_website`). Either change the pool's identity to a custom one or you can even use **that** `_website` identity - just go to your SQL server, add a new user, make it a Windows user of the name `IIS APPPOOL\_website` and add **permissions** for that user to your database.